# Display Transparent camera activity with default installed app on start acitivity

Tags: android, window, transparent

I want to like following, when application start open one activity that display transparent activity like following image,

[image]

Backgrounds is transparent ( like to start camera in backgrounds ) and other application and other menu are display at bottom as disply in image. **when application close, it close.** but when choose from livewallpapaer only that time it set as wallpaper ( that i done ) like transparent screen.

please help me to how to do like this ?,

Answer (score 0):

Define theme in style file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
      <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
      </style>
    </resources>
```

and give this theme to your activity... see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700683/2274724)..

Comment: it just to display screen,but i also want to display all like menu and other installed app, like main screen of mobile

Comment: no not like that please wait, i put some screen-shot.